# how to remove these packages from pip?

Tags: python, pip

I decided to start a fresh environment for Python and `pip`.  I ran the command:

`pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)`

Some packages were giving me permissions errors, so I `sudo pip uninstall` those, one of those being `certifi`

Now, when I run `pip list`:

```
Package    Version  
---------- ---------
-          rtifi    
-ailer     0.8.1    
-ertifi    2019.3.9 
-rtifi     2018.4.16
pip        19.0.3   
setuptools 40.9.0
```

which is very weird.

I have tried to:

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools`

but am still resulting in the same list.

How do I complete clean out my installed pip packages?

Comment: That's a hilarious failure mode! Don't `sudo pip`. The system site-packages is for the system only, and should not be messed with or you're gonna make your computer a big mess. To make a fresh environment, learn to use [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: @sgerbhctim, why don't you just create a virtual environment?

Comment: I do usually use them, but I wanted a base line interpreter to inherit from sometimes.

Comment: @sgerbhctim, you can also use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different versions of Python. What OS are you using?

Comment: MacOS 10.14.2, I set my `bash_profile` to recognize `python` as `python3` if that is what you are asking.. same as `pip3` to `pip`

Comment: `venv` doesn't care about what site-packages are installed in the underlying interpreter, that's the whole point. Trying to remove them to make a "fresh" environment is totally misguided.

Comment: I use `virtualenv`, I just want to clean my underlying interpreter now!

Comment: I don't know how many times to tell you. You don't want to "clean" the underlying interpreter. It's like opening up your car bonnet and removing random pieces of machinery to try and "clean" it. They're all there for a reason and it's the OS or package manager's job (probably `brew` or `macports` in your case) to make sure there's a consistent set of packages there on system level.